# Using the Oracle SCN keep track of modified rows

Tags: oracle

Can I rely on the Oracle SCN to keep track of modified rows in my database? The goal is to query the database every x minutes for all the rows which have been modified in a particular table. The idea was to remember the current SCN using

```
SELECT current_scn FROM V$DATABASE;
```

And then after x minutes I would just run a query like

```
SELECT * from mytable where ORA_ROWSCN > current_scn_x_minutes_ago;
```

to get all the rows which have changed since then (and thus have a higher SCN). I am aware that the query will return too many results as the SCNs are managed per block but this does not matter. The main question I have is whether the SCN is strictly increasing, i.e. whether the next generated SCN is always higher than the current SCN (as queried from V$DATABASE) or whether I have to rely on SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP function to be sure that the ordering is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The main question I have is whether the SCN is strictly increasing,
> i.e. whether the next generated SCN is always higher than the current
> SCN

According to the documentation: [ORA_ROWSCN Pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF50953)

> Whether at the block level or at the row level, the ORA_ROWSCN should
> not be considered to be an exact SCN. For example, if a transaction
> changed row R in a block and committed at SCN 10, it is not always
> true that the ORA_ROWSCN for the row would return 10. While a value
> less than 10 would never be returned, any value greater than or equal
> to 10 could be returned. That is, the ORA_ROWSCN of a row is not
> always guaranteed to be the exact commit SCN of the transaction that
> last modified that row. **However, with fine-grained ORA_ROWSCN, if two
> transactions T1 and T2 modified the same row R, one after another, and
> committed, a query on the ORA_ROWSCN of row R after the commit of T1
> will return a value lower than the value returned after the commit of
> T2**.
>
> If a block is queried twice, then it is possible for the value of
> ORA_ROWSCN to change between the queries even though rows have not
> been updated in the time between the queries. **The only guarantee is
> that the value of ORA_ROWSCN in both queries is greater than the
> commit SCN of the transaction that last modified that row.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We don't use fine-grained ORA_ROWSCN (using ROWDEPENDENCIES) and cannot recreate our tables with this setting. 
So the question is whether the mentioned rule also applies at block level, or to rephrase it:
"If transaction T1 modifies row R1 belonging to block B1 and transaction T2 modifies row R2 belonging to block B2, and T2 happens after T1, 
is ORA_ROWSCN of R1 after the commit of T1 guaranteed to be lower than ORA_ROWSCN of R2 after the commit of T2 (assuming we don't use fine-grained ORA_ROWSCN)?"